# SignalR on React Native error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server

Tags: signalr, react-native

This is how do the connection part.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const hubUrl = "https://192.168.1.106:45455/messagingHub";

    const connectionHub = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(hubUrl)
      .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
      .build();

    connectionHub.start().catch(err => console.log(err)); }
```

Before I post the error, It's not because of cors or anything related to the api. Api was started on my laptop and I used Conveyor by Keyoti to expose it to my local network and I installed Conveyor by Keyoti SSL certificate on my phone that shouldn't be a problem. And I was able to connect to the SignalR hub on my PC using a small console application I made and I was able to send messages and recieved them. So problem is on React Native part. About React Native I used expo cli, so it was a quick start react native.

This is the errors I get:

Http Warning
[image: The http warning]

3 Errors I get
[image: 1st Error]
[image: 2nd and 3rd Error]

And my Package.json
[image: Package.json]

Comment: Yooo did you ever figure this out.. I just started experiencing this as well?

Comment: Ya, it was a problem with SSL. SignalR on react doesn't really return you a good error description like ever, so I had to console log the error I get in SignalR myself. And it seems like Conveyor by Keyoti SSL certificate only works in browser, doesn't work in side some other app.